How to add module using org.gradle.api.Project.projects
On my current Android Project, I have a few modules that can depend on each other. e.g:
:feature:register can depend on :core:data through the build.gradle.kts with the syntax: implementation(project(":code:data"))
However, I've seen on projects like NowInAndroid that the modules are being accessed using the org.gradle.api.Project.projects, so the syntax looks like: implementation(projects.code.data)
On my project when I use such syntax the projects is not not recognized. How can I use it?

it looks like i figured it out.
According to this answer you need to add the line below to your settings.gradle.kts file:
enableFeaturePreview("TYPESAFE_PROJECT_ACCESSORS")

